# How to apply Executorservice on ArrayList

Tags: java, executorservice

In my `finalJSONProdRequest` List there are 500 list of rows.

I want list of data to be processed by Executor service in multiple  Threads. For this I made below class having 3 threads.

How can I ensure that `finalJSONProdRequest` data will be divided in 3 threads? Currently the same data goes to each Thread.

```
public class DummyExecutorService  {
    private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    public void executeAsynchronous(List<String> finalJSONProdRequest) {
        DummyExecutor task = new DummyExecutor (finalJSONProdRequest);
        service.execute(task);
        service.shutdown();
    }
}


public class DummyExecutor implements Runnable {
    public DummyExecutor (List<String> finalJSONProdRequest) {
        super();
        this.finalJSONProdRequest = finalJSONProdRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //LOGGER.debug("Inside run() of DummyExecutor ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently the same data goes to same threads as you are passing the list of 500 items, you need to pass the list with different content to achieve this. May be taking only 170, 170 and 160 and call it three times.

```
    DummyExecutor task1 = new DummyExecutor (finalJSONProdRequest1);
    DummyExecutor task2 = new DummyExecutor (finalJSONProdRequest2);
    DummyExecutor task3 = new DummyExecutor (finalJSONProdRequest3);
```

now submit these task.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the requests individually as a single task to the scheduler. So your `DummyExecutor` has to be rewritten to accept only a single `String` instead of a `List<String>` object. Then you can add the individual tasks to your scheduler:

```
for (String request: finalJSONProdRequest) {
    DummyExecutor task = new DummyExecutor (request);
    service.execute(task);
}
```

You still have only three threads working for your scheduler (as defined by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);`), but when a thread finishes his task it gets the next `DummyExecutor` task. Obviously this create a lot of tasks (not threads), so you must decide for yourself if this approach is suitable for your application.